# Snow Leopard dedicated partition size

Tags: mac, partitioning, osx-snow-leopard, upgrade

Coming from a Widows world I consider a system upgrade synonymous to problems and week-long headaches. I have a 320GB hard drive in my MacBook which is pretty much full (sometimes only 100MB to spare) and I don't have any means of backup right now (all my other hard drives are smaller and used for Windows/Ubuntu systems).

To keep this from happening in the future I'd like to have a partition for my files and one for the system.

I'd like to know what's the ideal partition size for a fresh Snow Leopard.

Would it be possible to change partition size when one gets too small and the other has room to spare (very optimistic here)?

Currently all my stuff weighs at 250GB, the system folder (Leopard) 4.5GB, developer 4.3GB, library 11.7GB (what's that for?) and applications 6GB. Does 30GB sound good to you?

Comment: You could have waited a bit before accepting my answer. There's a lot of Mac users on SU; maybe they would have had a different view on the matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Mac OS partition is about **30 GB**, which should be enough, really. I have XCode, a bunch of VMs and countless other stuff and have never really passed that much. All my personal stuff is on another partition, making things easier for me when it comes down to reinstalling Mac OS from scratch.

Comment: Well, 30GB it is.